# Why does both the forms are in single page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title</title>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.creditCardValidator.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="demo1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$('.tabHeader').click(function () {
    $('.demo form').hide().filter($(this).attr('href')).show()
    return false;
}).eq(0).click();

</script>



</head>

<div class="demo">
    <a href="#formA" class="tabHeader">Form A</a>
    <a href="#formB" class="tabHeader">Form B</a>
    <form id="formA">
         <h2>Card Payment</h2>

        <input type='hidden' id='ccType' name='ccType' />
        <ul class="cards">
            <li class="visa">Visa</li>
            <li class="visa_electron">Visa Electron</li>
            <li class="mastercard">MasterCard</li>
            <li class="maestro">Maestro</li>
        </ul>
        <label for="card_number">Card number</label>
        <input type="text" name="card_number" id="card_number">
        <div class="vertical">
            <label for="expiry_date">Expiry date <small>mm/yy</small>

            </label>
            <input type="text" name="expiry_date" id="expiry_date" maxlength="5">
            <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
            <input type="text" name="cvv" id="cvv" maxlength="3">
        </div>
        <div class="vertical maestro">
            <label for="issue_date">Issue date <small>mm/yy</small>

            </label>
            <input type="text" name="issue_date" id="issue_date" maxlength="5"> <span class="or">or</span>

            <label for="issue_number">Issue number</label>
            <input type="text" name="issue_number" id="issue_number" maxlength="2">
        </div>
        <label for="name_on_card">Name On card</label>
        <input type="text" name="name_on_card" id="name_on_card">
        <input type="submit" value="Pay Now !">
    </form>
    <form id="formB">Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />Email:
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />Comments:
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="25" rows="3"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

basically has two forms which can be selected using tabs.I have the java script

```
$('.tabHeader').click(function () {
    $('.demo form').hide().filter($(this).attr('href')).show()
    return false;
}).eq(0).click();
```

in the header which does the swapping.but when I implement this html file,both the forms are displayed in the page.
But this is the demo @http://jsfiddle.net/25WDr   here its working fine,but this html is not working.The js fiddle demo is done by a user here.but I cant implement it.It showing both form.The mistake is in the html i made..can anyone figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put your javascript code inside a  [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(function() {

    $('.tabHeader').click(function () {
        $('.demo form').hide().filter($(this).attr('href')).show()
        return false;
    }).eq(0).click();

});
```

Because in `head` part all your html is not built yet, So `$('.tabHeader')` is empty.

You should wait the end of load of your html part in order to manipulate it.
Another solution could be put your script before the `</body>`

Comment: Yeah thanks you so much! That was a real solution..It worked like charm..and @chumkiu why it really worked when I placed the script in the body?is it the same to what like the document ready ?

Answer (score 1):

in the demo they are actually hiding the other form while clicking the first

```
$(function() {
  $('<a>FormB</a>').prependTo('.demo').click(function () {
  $('.demo form').hide().filter('#formB').show()
  }).click();
  $('<a>FormA</a>').prependTo('.demo').click(function () {
  $('.demo form').hide().filter('#formA').show()
  }).click();

 });
```